# Fastest way to check for the existence of a specific item in a 30M line text file

Tags: ruby, database

I'm working with a large dataset that I need to query for the existance of specific items via Ruby.

If it helps, imagine a 30M line text file that lists SHA1 values. I'm trying to determine the fastest way of checking for the presence of a specific SHA1 value in that list.

I've experimented with splitting the file up into multiple, smaller files and grepping them, importing them into a database (which has been painful), and other options with varying degreess of success. Using a traditional database doesn't seem ideal, as I only need to check for the presence of an item.

Any recommendations on ways to query the dataset in the shortest amount of time?

Comment: Can you please clarify: do you need to query for the existence once only, or do you need to check for the existence of many different items over time?

Comment: @Phrogz To clarify, I need to check for the existence of many different items over time.

Comment: Can you leave the 'server' app running, or is this something you need to launch and quit, launch and quit? (What if there was a client connecting to a process that was left running as a daemon/service?)

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question saying *"existance of specific items"* (plural), I'll assume that you need to do this often on the same file. I'm assuming that the data does not change that often. Since you asked about speed, let's trade memory for speed:

1. Slurp the entire file into RAM.
2. Create a Hash with each SHA1 entry as a key pointing to something simple (e.g. `0`)
3. Get fast lookup on multiple items after this, e.g. `if hash.key?(sha1)`
4. If you can't leave the process running, dump the hash into a file on disk:

   ```
   File.open('hash.marshal','wb'){ |f| f.write Marshal.dump(hash) }
   ```

   ...and then later load that in all at once next time you run:

   ```
   hash = Marshal.load( File.open('hash.marshal','rb',&:read) )
   ```

**Edit**: I think you may be involved in premature optimization. Do you realize how fast computers are today? Here's what I see on my machine (admittedly, with a SSD):

Time to generate and write 1,000,000 random SHA1 hashes into a 39MB file: **2.7s**
Time to read in that 39MB file as a single string (`File.read`): **0.06s**
Time to read the lines of the file as an array (`File.readlines`): **0.3s**
Time to read as array and also remove newlines (`File.readlines().map(&:chomp)`): **0.8s**
Time to scan the array of 1,000,000 strings for a trivial non-match (`a.include?('foo')`): **0.04s**
Time to scan the array to find the last match (`a.include?(a.last)`): **0.06s**

It's **less than 1 second** to use the naive approach of reading in the entire file of 1,000,000 items and then search through it twice:

```
phrogz$ du -h sha1.txt 
 39M    sha1.txt

phrogz$ wc -l sha1.txt 
 1000000 sha1.txt

phrogz$ tail -5 sha1.txt 
52e3924f844d5b49f9b532763420a2cc8dee1652
e19aa567baa76c18b269fea1e40afe7ae984ac89
ee9359faf19a66df89dc4fd32fa8ec28ee0c9d27
88796129579a56488c0b38fab2bce36373f8df5e
1f5523a8f535289b3401b29958d01b2966ed61d2

phrogz$ irb
irb:001:0> def time; t = Time.now; yield; Time.now-t; end
#=> nil
irb:002:0> time do
irb:003:1*   a = IO.readlines('sha1.txt').map(&:chomp)
irb:004:1>   p a.include?('ee9359faf19a66df89dc4fd32fa8ec28ee0c9d27')
irb:005:1>   p a.include?('ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff')
irb:006:1> end
true
false
#=> 0.946468
```

Now, we find that loading the Hash from marshal is actually *slower* than loading the file into an array, but gobs faster, even when performing *thousands* of lookups:

```
phrogz$ irb
irb:001:0> File.open('sha1.marshal','wb') do |f|
irb:002:1*   h = Hash[ IO.readlines('sha1.txt').map(&:chomp).product([0]) ]
irb:003:1>   f.write Marshal.dump(h)
irb:004:1> end
#=> 49000008

phrogz$ du -h sha1.marshal 
 47M    sha1.marshal

irb:001:0> def time; t = Time.now; yield; Time.now-t; end
#=> nil
irb:002:0> time{ @h = Marshal.load( File.open('sha1.marshal','rb',&:read) ) }
#=> 2.035597
irb:003:0> time{1000.times{@h.key?('ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff')}}
#=> 0.000328
irb:004:0> time{1000.times{@h.key?('ee9359faf19a66df89dc4fd32fa8ec28ee0c9d27')}}
#=> 0.000232
```

Finally, as to memory usage:

- Loading the raw array of strings (in IRB): memory goes from 17 MB(real)/50 MB(virtual) to 235 MB(real)/270 MB(virtual). Calling `.include?` 1,000 times results in no change to memory usage.
- Loading the Marshal'd hash takes IRB from 17 MB(real)/50 MB(virtual) to 280 MB(real)/310 MB(virtual). It uses a bit more RAM on your machine. But RAM is cheap. Does your machine not have 300MB of RAM available?

Comment: Interesting idea. Seems like there will be issues with memory; we're talking about several dozen megs of data. I'll play around with it though -- thank you.

Comment: I'm blown away by how much help you've provided to a complete stranger. Thank you --

Answer (score 3):

Create directories with the first few letters of the SHA1 at each level... ie:

```
1/a/f/x
2/b/e/f
...
```

Where the last item in the directory structure contains the list of SHA1's with that prefix.  You can make it as deep or shallow as you want and it should be lightning fast.

Comment: This is effectively a trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), though does also require a specific data structure, rather than the 30M line text file :)

Comment: Ah yes, that's the word for it.  But all he needs to do is check for existence... I'm assuming a one column file with just a sha1 on it... Why wouldn't this work?

Comment: It will work ;)  I was just indicating that it's not a direct answer to the question (neither is mine), since it doesn't actually operate over the 30M line file (I'm guessing the OP has no control over the data structure).

Comment: I thought binary search at first too, but that requires keeping things sorted.  I think a Trie (via a datastructure or filesystem) would be considerably faster than a binary search.  Do you agree?

Comment: Not strictly.  A trie requires one read for every character in the SHA1 (40 reads), while a binary search is logarithmic (over the volume of data). You'd get there in 25 reads using the binary search.

Comment: Ah, actually, of course, you're right if you just convert the SHA1 to a full path without checking each directory in turn ;)  I'll +1 you, as this is most likely faster.

Comment: I don't think so.  Only with my very "naive" implementation.  It could be `1afx/21af4/` which gets there faster...  It's just managing how big each of the buckets should be.

Comment: Note that your last comment is an implementation of Radix Tree (Patricia Trie) ;)  Slower update time but faster read time.

Comment: Thanks for the fancy verbage ;)  I know there are names for these things, but I just understand the details and never learned the names...

Comment: Verbiage helps if you ever need a variation on something and don't know what to search for :) We'll have to end this in-comment chat, I think. Have to dash to work anyway!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent discussion. This is similar to my solution: I created did "/abcd/efgh" and in that directory I generated "aaaa.txt", "aaab.txt", etc which listed everything that begins with those letters. To look up a specific SHA1, I grep'd the file looking for the specific item. Sounds like that's what you're suggesting, yes? Any thoughts on how far to take it? For example, I *could* take it all the way out: "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h..../r.txt" and just check for the presence of that file to determine if a particular SHA exists. Are there downsides to such a massive file structure though?

Comment: Of course.  The deeper the file structure, the more filesystem interaction and slower it will be, however, start using it and profile the code.  That's the one way to be sure as to what will work fastest for you.  Consider not having a file to grep through at the end, but simply a file to test for existence.

Answer (score 2):

If the list is ordered, you probably want a binary search.  If the list is not ordered, there isn't a fast way, as there's no possible way to 'navigate' towards to the correct SHA1.

If you have to do this multiple times on the same data set, create an ordered copy then use that for the binary search.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: Thanks. I should clarify also: I do have the ability to manipulate the data structure. For example, I could order the list and then proceed with the lookups. Binary search sounds like a good option. Do you have any Ruby-specific recommendations for reading the file and then performing the binary search? Seems too large to read into memory.

Comment: Since a SHA1 has a fixed length, you can use `File#seek` to move around within the file, without reading the entire file into memory.  You'll just be seeking in blocks of 40 bytes + whatever the line ending is (1 byte, assuming UNIX endings).

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own binary-search index.

First, make an index of the locations in the file of each item. So, lets say the file is:

```
apple
banana
carrot
potato
tomato
zucchini
```

Let's consider this file as a binary string. It would look like this (spaces are `\n` for clarity):

```
apple banana carrot potato tomato zucchini
```

Our index would be an array of integers that represent the position of the start of each word in the file:

```
apple banana carrot potato tomato zucchini
|     |      |      |      |      |
0     6      13     20     27     31
```

So, your index is:

```
[0,6,13,20,27,31]
```

Now, use this index to do a binary search. Here's an example of how that would work:

1. Let's say you are searching for 'apple'
2. Choose a middle element from the index (20) as your pivot.
3. Seek to position 20 in your file and see if you are at the word you're looking for. Nope,  "apple" is smaller than (comes before) "potato". (You only have to compare 1 letter at a time)
4. Choose your next pivot from the smaller elements (`[0,6,13]`). We'll choose 6.
5. Seek to position 6 and see if it's our word. Nope, "apple" is smaller than "banana".
6. Remaining elements are `[0]`.
7. Seek to position 0, and we found our word.

## Edit

If you hash each item into a SHA1, it makes it easier. Because each hash is the same size, you don't need to keep an index on your file. Your index just looks like:

```
[0,k,2k,3k,4k,5k,6k]
```

Where `k` is the size of the hashes.

That means you can just keep a range of `(0..n)` as your "index" and use multiplication to figure out which position in the file to seek to.

Answer (score 0):

Why was DB import painful? That should normally be your first resort for a dataset this large. If you can explain more about your use case, I can probably be of more help.